# Does iPhone libffi require jailbreak?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval, libffi

I'd like to write an app-store-approvable app for the iPhone OS which uses libffi.  Is this allowed?  I am capable of rewriting all of the parts that use it with things like NSInvocation without too much trouble, but would prefer libffi.  So my question is: would apps that use libffi be rejected from the app store?

Comment: Question for the curious: What does libffi allow you to do that you can't already do in Objective-C? (In other words, why do you think you need it?)

Comment: Well I think libffi is faster, as it doesn't have the overhead of objc calls.  Really esoteric I suppose.

Comment: actually, I just remembered: calling c functions with the objc stuff is basically relegated to creating a singleton with methods for every possible c function, which (while automated) still seems like a hack, compared to libffi

Comment: Be careful that you are not optimizing prematurely, as Objective-C messages are not as expensive as you would think: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/performance-comparisons-of-common-operations-iphone-edition.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for Apple support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple approval is not guaranteed or denied by anything. It's entirely up to them.

Comment: Edited the question: would using libffi guarantee rejection

Comment: Answer stays the same, nothing guarantees acceptance or rejections.